# Angular 2 module communication

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular2-services

I have an external module and I want to enable the communication with the main app calling (from the app) a function on CustomModuleInterfaceService:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; import {CustomModuleInterfaceService} from './services/custom.module.interface.service'; 
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http"; 
import { CustomModuleComponent} from './custom.module.component'; 

@NgModule({ 
   imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule], 
   providers: [CustomModuleInterfaceService], 
   declarations: [CustomModuleComponent], 
   exports: [CustomModuleComponent] 
}) 

export class CustomModule { }
```

I imported my CustomModule in the app:

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [
     BrowserModule,
     routing,
     HttpModule,
     CustomModule
   ],
   declarations: [
     AppComponent   
   ],
   providers: [
     { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: LogService }
   ],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

export class AppModule { }
```

In my AppComponent I want to call a function on CustomModuleInterfaceService but it doesn't work:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CustomModuleInterfaceService} from '...';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})

export class AppComponent {
  private interfaceService : CustomModuleInterfaceService;

  constructor (_interface:CustomModuleInterfaceService) {  
    this.interfaceService = _interface;
    //MyFunction is defined in CustomModuleInterfaceService
    this.interfaceService.MyFunction(); 
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please don't use the snipped feature when the code isn't actually runnable inline. Use the `[ {} ]` toolbar button instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me with a basic service. The problem may be located on the service that you try to inject. Could you show the code of the service?  Be aware that injection of "interface" is detailed in the official documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#dependency-injection-tokens